# Fit data into machine learning keras model when data is huge

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, keras, numpy-ndarray

In machine learning tutorials using keras, the code to train the machine learning model is this typical one-liner.

```
model.fit(X_train, 
          Y_train, 
          nb_epoch=5, 
          batch_size = 128, 
          verbose=1, 
          validation_split=0.1)
```

This seems easy when the training data `X_train` and `Y_train` is small. `X_train` and `Y_train` are numpy ndarrays. In practical situations, the training data can go into gigabytes which may be too large to be even fitted into the RAM of the computer.

How do you send data into `model.fit()` when the training data is too huge?

Comment: consider using fit_generator, and load data from disk batch by batch inside generators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple solution for that in Keras. You can simply use python generators, where your data is lazy loaded. If you have Images you can also use the ImageDataGenerator.

```
def generate_data(x, y, batch_size):    
    while True:
        batch = []
        for b in range(batch_size):
           batch.append(myDataSlice)

        yield np.array(batch )

model.fit_generator(
generator=generate_data(x, y, batch_size),
steps_per_epoch=num_batches, 
validation_data=list_batch_generator(x_val, y_val, batch_size), 
validation_steps=num_batches_test)
```